# printing an X using while loops

Tags: c, while-loop

I want to write a program that reads an integer n from standard input, and prints an nxn pattern of asterisks and dashes in the shape of an "X".

N has to be odd and N>= 5.

**my code**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)  {
    
    //making sure they enter an odd number >= 5 
    
    int endloop = 0; 
    
    int size;
    while (endloop == 0) { 
        printf("Enter size:");
        scanf("%d", &size);
        if (size % 2 == 0 || size < 5) {
            printf("Invalid, try again\n");
        } else {
            endloop = 1;
        } 
    }
    
   
    int downwards = 0;
    while (downwards < size) {
    
        int across = 0; 
        while (across < size) {
            if (downwards == across) {
                printf("*");
            }
            if (across == size - downwards - 1) {
                printf("*");
            } else {
                printf("-");
            }
            across++; 
        }
        downwards++;
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    return 0; 
}
```

**result:**

```
Enter size:5
*----*
-*--*-
--**--
-*-*--
*---*-
```

it's supposed to look like this:

```
*---*
-*-*-
--*--
-*-*-
*---*
```

i can't figure out what i did wrong. The across row is printing 6 characters instead of 5 even though i stated across < size

Comment: `if (across == size - downwards - 1)` --> `else if (across == size - downwards - 1)` or remove that `if` altogether and merge it with the first one: `if (downwards == across || (across == size - downwards - 1))`

Comment: Ahh that was really silly of me, thank you so much!!